# Angular2 Node and npm install

Tags: angular

The documentation says "
Verify that you are running at least node v4.x.x and npm 3.x.x by running node -v and npm -v in a terminal/console window. Older versions produce errors.

Then the link just below it downloads node v4 but npm 2.15.8

Am I missing something or is somebody asleep at the wheel ??

Comment: Did you try it yet or are you just complaining about vague//incomplete documentation?

Comment: No worked find, no problems. Documentation is really incomplete tho, mostly the summaries but those are the most useful part to people ramping up. Really great to get a real language for the front end tho, and with both MS and Google behind it it seems like a real safe bet to put my eggs in this basket. Go some corrections for the Docs by the way, where do I submit them?

Answer (score 1):

if you go here: [https://nodejs.org/en/](http://NodeJS)

There are 2 options:

**LTS**: Current version: v4.4.7 (includes npm 2.15.8)

**Current**: Current version: v6.3.0 (includes npm 3.10.3)

You most likely downloaded LTS version

Comment: FYI Thanks for the help, The original link did not display the choice on my Mac